# Neo4j Using a custom evaluator to get the depth a node was retrieved at

Tags: java, api, neo4j, evaluator

I'm using the latest version of Neo4j to build up a graph of nodes and relationships with the Java API.

My problem is that I need to traverse the nodes to a certain depth. There may exist a relationship between two nodes at the same depth in the database, but I don't want to return that relationship in the traversal.

I tried to make a custom Evaluator by implementing the Evaluator interface but the only method it overrides is `Evaluation evaluate(Path path)` . It doesn't appear to have the notion of depth associated with it.

I would really appreciate some advice on how to either associate a node with its depth (when traversing from a particular node) or prune a relationship where two nodes are in the same level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Evaluators.atDepth()](http://api.neo4j.org/current/org/neo4j/graphdb/traversal/Evaluators.html#atDepth%28int%29) to get a predefined Evaluator that only includes paths with a certain depth.

In your custom evaluator you can simply check the length of the passed path parameter to decide if you want to include this path or not e.g. with:

```
Evaluation evaluate(Path path) {
    return path.length() == 4 ? Evaluation.INCLUDE_AND_PRUNE : Evaluation.EXCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Cypher](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/cypher-query-lang.html) for that, something like

```
start n = node(1) match p=n-[*4]->(x) return x, length(p)
```

?

Answer (score 0):

The path has a length(), which is the depth. The length is equal to the number of relationships in the path, i.e. number of nodes - 1.